# Forwarding the value category of a container?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

In C++20 I want to write generic code to take a container or a view and perfectly forward each element. That is, if I have an obnoxious type like this:

```cpp
struct S {
    struct tag {}; // So we have a way to construct an S.
    S(tag) {}

    S() = delete; // S isn't semiregular.
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S(S&&) = default; // It's movable
    S& operator=(const S&) = delete;
    S& operator=(S&&) = default;
};
```

I want to be able to pass a `std::vector<S>` to a function and have it consume the `S`es.

I had originally assumed that this would work:

```cpp
template <typename Range, typename Fn>
void myForEach(Range&& range, Fn f) {
    for (auto&& x : std::forward<Range>(range)) {
        f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
    }
}
```

but even if `FWD(range)` is an rvalue, `x` isn't, so if `f` needs an `S&&`, this won't work.

C++23 adds [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like) which seems close. In particular:

```cpp
template <typename Range, typename Fn>
void myForEach(Range&& range, Fn f) {
    for (auto&& x : range) {
        f(std::forward_like<Range>(x));
    }
}
```

will forward the value category of the range... but what if the range is a view? If `Range&&` winds up being `std::span<S>&&`, I don't want the rvalue-ness of the span to apply tho the `S`! I think (?) we'd want to consider `std::ranges::enable_view<Range>` and if so, ignore the value category of `Range&&` and just use the value category from te dereferenced iterator.

Furthermore we'd want this to work for ranges of `std::move_iterator` and for generators.

Is there any standard C++ functionality for this?

I've found similar questions, but they aren't up-to-date or don't quite get to my point. E.g., [Universal Reference of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588873/universal-reference-of-vector)

Comment: It looks like sometimes you want to move the elements out and sometimes you don't, depending on what kind of range it is. If it's an owning range like a vector, you do, and if it's a non-owning range like a view, you don't. The compiler however has no idea what's owning and what's not.

Comment: Right, but it has `enable_view` which, if everyone is using it, can tell us if the value category of the range is the value category we care about.

Comment: Then you can overload based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve come to conclude that the core issue is that C++ containers make no attempt to propagate their value category. That is, `std::optional<int>&&` has a `.value()` of type `int&&` but `std::vector<int>&&` doesn’t have `*v.begin()` as an `int&&`. That said…

I think this answers my question, but it is dangerous and so likely shouldn't be used:

```cpp
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <ranges>
    #include <type_traits>
    #include <utility>
    #include <vector>


    #define FWD(...) static_cast<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)&&>(__VA_ARGS__)

    // C++23's std::forward_like:
    template<class T, class U>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto&& forward_like(U&& x) noexcept {
        constexpr bool is_adding_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
        if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T&&>)
        {
            if constexpr (is_adding_const)
                return std::as_const(x);
            else
                return static_cast<U&>(x);
        }
        else
        {
            if constexpr (is_adding_const)
                return std::move(std::as_const(x));
            else
                return std::move(x);
        }
    }

    // Useful for debugging:
    template <typename> struct SayIt;

    //! A forwarding function that does what I'm looking for.
    //! Beware: If std::ranges::enable_view<Range> isn't specialized when it should, this will assume ownership semantics!
    //! Most uses of std::ranges::enable_view<Range> are opt-in, with safe behavior if it's not correclty specialized.
    //! This is dangerous: If you have a veiw that doesn't specialize that, it will treat it as owning.
    template<class Range, class U, class V>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto&& forward_element_of(V&& x) noexcept {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<U&&, decltype(x)>, "You have to name the type of x explicitly and correctly.");
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<Range>()))>>, 
                                    std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(x)>>>);
        //! If it's a view, ignore the constness and value-category of Range, just look at x:
        if constexpr (std::ranges::enable_view<Range>) {
            return FWD(x);
        } else {
            // It's not a view: 
            if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(x)>) {
                return std::move(x);
            }
            if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Range>) {
                return forward_like<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::remove_reference_t<Range>>>(FWD(x));
            } else {
                return forward_like<Range>(FWD(x));
            }
        }
    }


    template <typename Range>
    [[nodiscard]] auto forwarded_view_elements_of(Range&& range) {
        return FWD(range) | std::views::transform([](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
            return forward_element_of<Range, decltype(x)>(FWD(x));
        });
    }

    template <typename Range, typename F>
    void for_each_with_forwarding(Range&& in, F f) {
        for (auto&& x : forwarded_view_elements_of(FWD(in))) {
            f(FWD(x));
        }
    }

    // Useful for examples:
    [[nodiscard]] auto move_range_view(auto&& range) {
        return std::ranges::subrange(std::make_move_iterator(std::ranges::begin(range)), 
                                    std::make_move_iterator(std::ranges::end(range)));
    }

    int main() {
        // Examples:
        {   // By-value:
            auto foo = std::vector<int>{};
            for_each_with_forwarding(foo, [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });
            // Owning => constness propagates:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::as_const(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), const int&>); });
            // Owning => move propagates:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::move(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });        
        }
        {   // A view:
            auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
            auto foo = std::ranges::subrange(vec); //< A view.
            for_each_with_forwarding(foo, [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });
            // Constness doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::as_const(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });
            // Move doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::move(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });        
        }
        {   // Transform that just forwards (should do the same as a simple view with std::ranges::subrange).
            auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
            auto foo = vec | std::views::transform([](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return FWD(x); });
            for_each_with_forwarding(foo, [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });
            // Constness doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::as_const(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });
            // Move doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::move(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&>); });        
        }
        {   // Transform that returns a value:
            auto vv = std::vector<int>{};
            auto foo = vv | std::views::transform([](auto&& x) { return FWD(x); });
            for_each_with_forwarding(foo, [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });
            // Constness doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::as_const(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });
            // Move doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::move(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });        
        }
        {   // A move view:
            auto vec = std::vector<int>{};
            auto foo = move_range_view(vec);
            for_each_with_forwarding(foo, [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });
            // Constness doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::as_const(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });
            // Move doesn't propagate:
            for_each_with_forwarding(std::move(foo), [](auto&& x) { static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), int&&>); });        
        }
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/axs7W3svn

The function `forward_element_of<Range, Elt>(x)` checks if `std::ranges::enable_view<Range>`: If so, it just forwards `x`. If not, then it assumes it's owned and so propagates the value category and constness of `Range`. Then

```cpp
    template <typename Range>
    [[nodiscard]] auto forwarded_view_elements_of(Range&& range) {
        return FWD(range) | std::views::transform([](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) {
            return forward_element_of<Range, decltype(x)>(FWD(x));
        });
    }
```

is the useful use, creating a view of elements of that type, constness, and value-category.

Again, this seems dangerous for a variety of reasons, but I think this is the answer I was looking for. Ultimately, explicitly overloading is much more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a parameter of type `std::vector<...>&&` to pass elements to `f` as rvalue references, you need to implement specialized functionality for `std::vector<...>&&` parameters, e.g. by adding an overload. This is necessary, since `std::vector` does not provide any iterators that yield rvalue references when dereferencing them. I recommend introducing a function with a different name though(e.g. `myForEachMove`), since this is reuseable for types other than `std::vector` and makes it easier to determine what's happending in the code.

In any other case your first implementation works fine.

You could use need to use C++23's [`std::ranges::as_rvalue_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/as_rvalue_view) or use something like [`std::ranges::transform_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) or a subrange constructed using `std::move_iterator` to make sure the ranged for loop yields rvalue references for ranges that don't provide rvalue references.

```
struct Object
{
};

struct Functor
{
    void operator()(Object&&) const
    {
        std::cout << "f(Object&&)\n";
    }

    void operator()(Object&) const
    {
        std::cout << "f(Object&)\n";
    }

    void operator()(Object const&) const
    {
        std::cout << "f(Object const&)\n";
    }
};

template<std::ranges::range Range, class F>
void myForEach(Range&& r, F f)
{
    for (auto&& x : r)
    {
        f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
    }
}

int main()
{
    Functor f;

    // range providing lvalue references
    std::cout << "myForEach(std::vector<Object>&&, Functor)\n";
    myForEach(std::vector<Object>(2), f);

    // range modified via transform_view to provide rvalue references
    std::cout << "myForEach(decltype(transform_view(...))&&, Functor)\n";
    myForEach(std::ranges::transform_view(std::vector<Object>(2), []<class T>(T & e) -> T&& { return std::move(e); }), f);
    
    {
        // subrange with move iterator
        std::vector<Object> v(2);
        std::cout << "myForEach(subrange<...>, Functor)\n";
        myForEach(std::ranges::subrange(std::move_iterator(v.begin()), std::move_sentinel(v.end())), f);
    }

    {
        // range providing lvalue references to const
        std::vector<Object> v(2);
        std::cout << "myForEach(std::vector<Object> const&, Functor)\n";
        myForEach(static_cast<std::vector<Object> const&>(v), f);
    }

    // range providing prvalues
    std::cout << "myForEach(decltype(transform_view(...))&&, Functor)\n";
    myForEach(std::ranges::transform_view(std::vector<Object>(2), []<class T>(T& e) -> T { return std::move(e); }), f);

    {
        // another range providing lvalue references
        std::vector<Object> v(2);
        std::cout << "myForEach(std::span<Object, 2> &&, Functor)\n";
        myForEach(std::span<Object, 2>(v), f);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
myForEach(std::vector<Object>&&, Functor)
f(Object&)
f(Object&)
myForEach(decltype(transform_view(...))&&, Functor)
f(Object&&)
f(Object&&)
myForEach(subrange<...>, Functor)
f(Object&&)
f(Object&&)
myForEach(std::vector<Object> const&, Functor)
f(Object const&)
f(Object const&)
myForEach(decltype(transform_view(...))&&, Functor)
f(Object&&)
f(Object&&)
myForEach(std::span<Object, 2> &&, Functor)
f(Object&)
f(Object&)
```

[Code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbk4KBMSYrIfYJhoAgpvbu5gHR8SGwJgKVzf3ZlsMOy8%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%2BwkszxEKv0HWtMzrTMIv4hQvCiddnlQwgEBi8E9kIQs/LRpkfLM/zjp%2B0EgrC8nGXqlstW0m15sM7ysZxkFhsGq5xoc4gppcpHw3PFqFqMxccbWkBMexnc9rVCHwUykmvRICBQUGmJgCYsi90XVXMEypRBCmWhtcG1w%2BUN0Kxco8KQ1Y9Goo3YTRPEowpLKuTAaq5TPnyytpXLRmwbVA6/KOktafpx2G2W6NNKajnFspw63AC4jQ5lY1BbMkX01mxDFXT6X6kcZBMtEGUjkzmPs5p3Oe2NQLQQRhnEOo51EMinHCq9/AfeEv3arU5ONMatndQrh92s6qGNt6nahpGs124LtiheLmbWPn5Wl1W9bl024htv63bG/M5u4%2BI%2BnzvNS7rrcW77qeh%2BnvAj69m%2B3OXrykBsDYgoNjaQ2huROGXduIowQuLPYkVDCoAIAgWI7tnie2KhJX2skKqBxqqpMuFNk7R1vjnbAzIE6lwQczVOs9mr6U5kfBQSRDDUxLHuVylCxo7yLn2EursmSH0XKw9hscIRcI7jAmhw46R4g4AsWgnBzS8D8BwLQpBUCcDbJYawyolgrGeJsHgpACCaEUQsAA1iADYGxBp2McU45xtllEcEkGoixWjOC8DWhoMxFiFhwFgEgTAqhqggTIBQICxBgAKGUIYTAtAhAIFQKhdRpi0AzjoDyDICSwjJNSekrxWSkh0AGHE5gSQFCpIIKQUp5TiDhFYGsXgDT6DECRDGFJaT1GaLCdUW4sS1ocF4AM5AdQR4%2BJkIIEQYh2BSBmfIJQagvG6C4Pod4KBrDWH0HgKIa1IALE5I4KsnBPoqkOHiUwejLBmE0QoQxqw9AqlCPkpJPTincF4KhN4SROA8CUSozxGjeDaI4NgcJyBIkQQABwik%2BiKSQexgDIGQIBM41IrESggLoqwlg9y4EIJxExcxeDmNBYbNBTAsBxD5KQGxdiHHOJZXY1xnAPGkD6WC6ZfiAmUtIMExAIBxmRPIJQBocT3mFN6QCtpqBslzjyYkmVXzNHtIGLdIwmVMUMCsfUhVZSOnNLYNMjVnTulFO5YEKFQy4nTPGZM0I0z%2BCzNEOIRZrrlkqHUKC0gugAgGCMNs25NhaD7MOfSk5GQRkXMjFcm5%2BKLD3N8U8hZQwR7Ss%2BRkn5fy5VAo4KorlXjwWQoiZCOFCKkX7neBi%2BEeqcV4t2XsIlFbSXksCdY2x9jWWsv0BykFmjwW%2BJAP4ilWhDZuLMIOnloz%2BUToWOCYgaRnCSCAA)